# How can I create a bar chart where the bars are stacked in front of (overlaying) one another?

Tags: r, stacked-chart

For each date value (day), I want to show (as an overlayed bar) how many calls were missed and how many were completed.

Ideally, it will look like this (produced in Tableau):

[image]

The green section of the bars represent the portion of chats that were completed (if applicable), so in this example the user sees that there was 1 completed chat on 1st April 2018 and 4 missed chats, even though the `Total` bar does in fact possess a value of 5.

This code doesn't match the Tableau example (as it doesn't display `Total`), but it is headed in the right direction:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(new_data, aes(x = date,
                 y = count,
                 fill = type)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("forestgreen", "red")) +
  geom_bar(data = new_data[new_data$retailer == "Retailer 1", ],
           colour = "black",
           stat = "identity") +
  ggtitle("Completed vs. Missed Calls") +
  geom_bar(data = new_data[new_data$retailer == "Retailer 2", ],
           colour = "black",
           stat = "identity") +
  facet_grid(retailer~.)
```

It produces this graph:

[image]

The problem with this graph is that the bars are stacked on top of one another.  In this example, the `Missed` (red) column in the facet representing `Retailer 1` will be slightly taller than the green (`Completed`) column if placed behind it, which is how I want it to appear.

What I want to do is to stack one bar **in front** of the other.

My question is this: how do I produce something that shows the missed chats on top of the completed chats?  The best I can come up with is the bars being stacked on top of one another.

My data:

```
date            type        count   retailer
April 17 2018   Completed   12      Retailer 1
April 17 2018   Missed      13      Retailer 1
April 18 2018   Completed   10      Retailer 2
April 18 2018   Completed   11      Retailer 1
April 18 2018   Missed      5       Retailer 1
April 19 2018   Completed   10      Retailer 1
April 19 2018   Missed      1       Retailer 1
April 20 2018   Completed   2       Retailer 2
April 20 2018   Missed      1       Retailer 1
April 21 2018   Completed   2       Retailer 1
April 21 2018   Completed   1       Retailer 2
April 21 2018   Missed      1       Retailer 1
April 23 2018   Completed   2       Retailer 1
April 23 2018   Missed      2       Retailer 2
```

**NOTE:**

A future iteration (or the eventual evolution) of this graph will show a `Total` column (which is the summed value of `Completed` and `Missed`) in the background and the `Missed` column in front.  The result is, in fact, an "illusion" of sort, with difference between `Total` and `Missed` representing the number of `Completed` chats.  In short, `Missed` will always be less than or equal to the total (because all chats on a certain day could have been missed. (`Missed <= Total`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solves your problem with `tidyr` (for `spread`), `dplyr` (for `mutate`) and `ggplot2`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

my_df %>%
  spread(type, count, fill = 0) %>%   # Spread the count column in missed and completed
  mutate(Total = Completed + Missed) %>%   # Create the Total column
  ggplot(aes(date, Total)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = "Total")) + # total bar (with stat = "identity")
  geom_col(aes(y = Missed, fill = "Missed")) + # missed bar
  geom_text(aes(label = paste("Total chats:", Total)), # add total label
                hjust = -0.05, vjust = 1) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste("Missed chats:", Missed)), # add missed label
                hjust = -0.05, vjust = -0.5, color = "red") + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "",  # Manual fill scale
                    values = c("Total" = "forestgreen", "Missed" = "red")) +
  facet_grid(retailer~.) +  # Displayed per retailer
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 40)) + # Make labels visible
  coord_flip() + # switch x and y axes
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: This is absolutely perfect!  I have selected this as my chosen answer, but have also awarded you an upvote for the effort!